Symbology, displacement central point along the line QGIS
I'm trying to symbolize two-way streets. I've used this symbolization for each direction, but I can't move the triangle from the center of the line. I don't know which function should be applied?


Where do you want to have the triangle?

It looks like you are in the right place but maybe there is an issue with units

Displacement along the line moves the marker further down the line, not to the right or left of the line.

Yes, that is what I want. When the location of the marker is on first/last vertex, the option displacement along the line is available, but not when the option is on central point.

So, to clarify the question, since it isn't currently: You have lines. On each of your lines you want to display two arrows/triangles pointing down to each end of the line. Those triangles should be placed somewhere near halfway down the line, but not exactly there. Which distance between triangles is mandatory, which distance shouldn't be exceeded?

I really don't know which distance between triangles is mandatory and which distance shouldn't be exceeded. If these options were available, I would try several distances, and I would choose the one I liked.
